# gwt uiBinder ui:field access problem

Tags: gwt, field, uibinder

I have this in my ui.xml file:

```
<g:Button ui:field="saveButton"/>
```

This is in my view class:

```
@UiField
Button saveButton;

@Inject
public MyView() {

    saveButton.setText("Save");

    initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
}
```

If I run it as is, I get blank screen. But if I remove the `saveButton.setText("Save");` the button will come up but without any text in it. `BTW I'm using mvp4g`

#### Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@UiField without provided have to go under the initWidget call and @UiField(provided = true) has to go above the initWidget call.

```
@Inject
public MyView() {    
    // here go all UiFields with provided=true 
    initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
    // here go all UiFields without provided
    saveButton.setText("Save");
}
```

Comment: Actually, what matters is `createAndBindUi`, not `initWidget`; and with provided=true, what matters is that you **initialize** the field before the `createAndBindUi`, you can of course use the field's value whenever you want. Non-provided fields are however initialized by the `createAndBindUi` call, so you cannot use the field's value before that.